# Hadoop 2.5.1 MapReduce freezes

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I am on Ubuntu 14.04 and Installed Hadoop 2.5.1

My `jps` command gives me all resource information, so I know hadoop is running properly!

I try and run the MapReduce example on distributed system from [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.5.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html#Pseudo-Distributed_Operation)

But after certain point the job freezes

```
hduser@stratageeks-DL-E35LM1-R2:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.5.1.jar grep input output 'dfs[a-z.]+'
14/09/24 00:13:02 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
14/09/24 00:13:14 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
14/09/24 00:13:20 WARN mapreduce.JobSubmitter: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See Job or Job#setJar(String).
14/09/24 00:13:21 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 30
14/09/24 00:13:25 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:30
14/09/24 00:13:30 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1411497776309_0001
14/09/24 00:13:33 INFO mapred.YARNRunner: Job jar is not present. Not adding any jar to the list of resources.
14/09/24 00:13:35 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1411497776309_0001
14/09/24 00:13:35 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://stratageeks-DL-E35LM1-R2:8088/proxy/application_1411497776309_0001/
14/09/24 00:13:35 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1411497776309_0001
```

I have even increased my memory usage in yarn-site.xml to 4096 but still freezes

```
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
<value>4096</value>
<description>Physical memory, in MB, to be made available to running containers</description>
</property>
```

Any more suggestions..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it in `yarn-site.xml`

For some reason one of the property doesn't accept a `.` hence replaced with a `_`

```
  <property>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
  <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
  </property>
  <property>
```

Initially my value was

```
  <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
```

Comment: what's the difference? initially is `mapreduce.shuffle`? so, in the xml file, any `.` should be replaced with `_` for Hadoop2.5.1 on ubuntu14?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked all the logs for errors? Also the job-specific logs under `userlogs` folder (especially syslog) ?
The error files often give good clues about the actual problem.